# open a console on a virtual machine

Tags: qemu, linux-kvm

I have a KVM Virtual machine running, I can see that using "ps aux | grep kvm". 
What I need to open a console into that VM. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`virsh console DOMAIN` will open a terminal connected to serial console of DOMAIN.

Comment: I get this error when I try that:


 virsh # list --all
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
 25 one-36               running


virsh # console one-36
No console available for domain